# How to force DataGridView current cell outline without pressing Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

Is there someway to make it so the current cell of the `DataGridView` always has the dashed-line border around it that you get when you press the `Tab` button?  I've noticed that if you've pressed the `Tab` button once after that the current cell always has the border around it, but I'd like to have that border there from the start, without having to press the `Tab` button.

Currently I'm programmatically sending the Tab key, as below:

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
```

But this is kludgy and I'd rather have a proper solution if one is available.

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention that the `SelectionMode` is set to `FullRowSelect` and I'm not looking to change this.  I want the border outline around just the current cell as well as the whole row being highlighted.

Comment: Did you try to set the `CurrentCell` property ?

Comment: Setting the `CurrentCell` doesn't give me the border around the cell like pressing Tab does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a new class to inherit from `DataGridView` and override the `ShowFocusCues` property - returning `True` to *always* show the focus rectangle or `False` to *never* show it. You could even add a public property to expose it if you want to change it on a whim.

```
public class DataGridViewFocused : DataGridView
{
    public bool ShowFocus { get; set; }

    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ShowFocus;
        }
    }
}

DataGridViewFocused dataGridView1 = new DataGridViewFocused();
dataGridView1.ShowFocus = true;
```

Note: This will only focus the `CurrentCell` as that is just how it behaves.  So even with `FullRowSelect` set, only one of the selected cells in the highlighted row will be focused.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior seems to be hardcoded in windows forms. I don't think you could find a better way to code it.

One suggestion I can propose you is to handle the `DataGridView.CellPainting` event and to draw manually the border. You will then be able to draw the border with the style you want, so that the current cell could be more visible for the user than with the "TAB" method. Here is an example with a red dashed border :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell != null && e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1 &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex == e.RowIndex &&
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == e.ColumnIndex)
    {
        e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, e.PaintParts);
        var pen = new Pen(Color.Red) { DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash };
        var rect = new Rectangle(e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Width - 2, e.CellBounds.Height - 2);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JPProgrammer **If** you want *all* selected cells to have the focus rectangle, this method would work with some modification: Use `DashStyle.Dot` for the same look as the default. Also change the if-statement to `if (e.RowIndex != -1 && e.ColumnIndex != -1 && dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex] != null && dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Selected)`

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but a very useful solution nonetheless!