# How can I hide the current cell position on a DataGridView control?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control that allows for multi row selecting.  The issue I have is with the current position of the selection being shown (see image below).  I would like to NOT have the current cell **position** shown at all.  Is that possible?

[image]

I would like it to look like the following instead...

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to force DataGridView current cell outline without pressing Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35282436/3773066). My solution there should work for you, just set `ShowFocus` to `false`.

Comment: It took forever to go back and copy everything I had set up from one DataGridView to the other but this worked exactly as I wanted.  Thanks for making a painstaking process out of something so dang simple Microsoft!  - OhBeWise, add an answer to get the gold.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derive a class from `DataGridView` and override the `ShowFocusCues` property.

- Return `True` to show the focus rectangle.
- Return `False` to hide the focus rectangle.
- Return `base.ShowFocusCues` to maintain default behavior.

You can also expose a public property to change it dynamically.

```
public class DataGridViewFocused : DataGridView
{
    public bool? ShowFocus { get; set; }

    protected override bool ShowFocusCues
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ShowFocus.HasValue? this.ShowFocus.Value : base.ShowFocusCues;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Adding it to your project to replace any existing `DataGridView` can be as simple as navigating into your `Form.Designer.cs` file and replacing the following:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1; 
this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
```

with:

```
public DataGridViewFocused dataGridView1; 
this.dataGridView1 = new DataGridViewFocused();
```

From there you can always hide the focus rectangle by adding the following line:

```
this.dataGridView1.ShowFocus = false;
```

Or, for example, if you wanted to hide that rectangle *only* during a multiple-select event, you could do something like the following:

```
private void DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count > 1)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.ShowFocus = false;
    }
    else
    {
        this.dataGridView1.ShowFocus = null;
    }
}
```

[image: Default behavior on Tab + hiding focus rectangle on multi-select]